# Monitor Cassandra active connection using JMXMeter

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to use JMXMeter to monitor Cassandra active connection; however as per documentation when i run following then it should get result as below

```
$>info
#mbean = org.apache.cassandra.db:type=Commitlog
#class name = org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.
PeriodicCommitLogExecutorService
# attributes
%0 - ActiveCount (int, r)
%1 - CompletedTasks (long, r)
%2 - PendingTasks (long, r)
#there’s no operations
#there’s no notifications
```

However I am getting as below

```
$>info
#mbean = org.apache.cassandra.db:type=Commitlog
#class name = org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog
# attributes
  %0   - ActiveSegmentNames (java.util.List, r)
  %1   - ArchivingSegmentNames (java.util.List, r)
  %2   - CompletedTasks (long, r)
  %3   - PendingTasks (long, r)
  %4   - TotalCommitlogSize (long, r)
# operations
  %0   - void recover(java.lang.String p1)
#there's no notifications
```

As you note; I am not getting ActiveCount() attribute instead of that I am getting ActiveSegmentNames () and ArchivingSegmentNames(). I am looking for attribute to monitor acitve connection.

I am using apache-cassandra-1.2.3.

Please help.

Thanks,
Dilip

Answer (score 1):

You can get the count from the list of names by just taking the size of the list, but Commitlog segments count has never been related to the number of connections.  For that you'd want to ask the OS about TCP connections on your Thrift (or native protocol) port.